# Regex to match a url/link with line breaks in it

Tags: php, regex

What regex would match the link below with line breaks in it and "=". I am currently using this regex but it is not matching all of it:

```
((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.\,]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)
```

This is the example link:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/e/-eiijvz-h8zq2onn-2/VHWTzmPYQo40LPs2VhS6b_Nyx0MiE=
3in240VQyyWqfjjL007hj1UF1JEF-nYdDR/blk/I319184359351_65/0UcDpKqiRzolZKqiRybmR=
SrCBvrmRLoORIrmkZt5YCpnlOt3RApnhMpmdzgmasdhxrSNBszYRdBYNdjcVe34Vcjd9bSRjjS5dh=
CAQbPoUdzATdjsScPALrCBxbOYWrSlI/eml-comm_invm-b-in_ac-inv28/?hs=3Dfalse&to=
k=3D2PRdy1KvKbNls1
```

Comment: Can you put what you are trying to match into human terms? It is not clear what your matching criteria is.

Comment: Another solution: Remove the newlines before matching. `implode` helps.

Comment: I am trying to match the example link given in the question. I can not remove the line breaks as I need to replace the link with something else at a later date hence i need to keep the entire string in contact.

Comment: you can parse link with parse_url -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Not trying to parse the link trying to match it within a string

Comment: A valid URL does not contain newlines. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem - spammers trying to obfuscate their URLs by breaking them up multiple times with '=\n'.

Try this regex - it seems to work pretty well.  It matches URLs that are broken TWO OR MORE times.  It's unlikely a valid URL will be broken up in this manner more than once.

```
['"]https?:\/\/(?:\S*=\s){2,}(?:\S*)['"]
```

And if they're putting breaks within the http, there's this (a little hacky)

```
['"]h(?:=\s)?t(?:=\s)?t(?:=\s)?p(?:=\s)?s?:(?:=\s)?\/(?:=\s)?\/(?:\S*=\s){2,}(?:\S*)['"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.\,\=]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)
```

Comment: Nope that seems to cut off at seems to match http://www.linkedin.com/e/-eiijvz-h8zq2onn-2/VHWTzmPYQo40LPs2VhS6b_Nyx0MiE= for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for `https?://(\S+|(?<==)\n)*`
2. If match found, replace each occurrence of `=\n` with empty string